# Seperate datetime in python and counting hours

Tags: python, pandas, data-processing

| Nama | No.ID | Tgl/Waktu | No.PIN | Kode Verifikasi |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Alif | 100061 | 17/12/2022 07:53:26 |  | Sidik Jari |
| Alif | 100061 | 17/12/2022 13:00:25 |  | Sidik Jari |
| Alif | 100061 | 19/12/2022 07:54:59 |  | Sidik Jari |
| Alif | 100061 | 19/12/2022 16:18:14 |  | Sidik Jari |
| Alif | 100061 | 20/12/2022 07:55:54 |  | Sidik Jari |
| Alif | 100061 | 20/12/2022 16:16:16 |  | Sidik Jari |
| Alif | 100061 | 21/12/2022 07:54:46 |  | Sidik Jari |
| Alif | 100061 | 21/12/2022 16:15:41 |  | Sidik Jari |
| Alif | 100061 | 22/12/2022 07:55:54 |  | Sidik Jari |
| Alif | 100061 | 22/12/2022 16:15:59 |  | Sidik Jari |
| Alif | 100061 | 23/12/2022 07:56:26 |  | Sidik Jari |
| Alif | 100061 | 23/12/2022 16:16:56 |  | Sidik Jari |

So I have a few questions in this thread. the first one is from the table above how to separate the Tgl/Waktu column from the excel file into 2 separate new column that is date and time.

then how do I count the total work hour from that code, I have an idea where you subtract the bigger hour to the lower one when the date is the same, but I cant execute it

Comment: Please [edit] to convert your images of text into actual text. [See here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541) for why. See also: ["how to format a table in a post"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/277716/11107541).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there were no lunch breaks, the hours worked can be calculated by simple max - min subtraction:

```
df['Tgl/Waktu'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Tgl/Waktu'])
df['date'] = df['Tgl/Waktu'].dt.date
df['time'] = df['Tgl/Waktu'].dt.time
hours_worked = (df.groupby(by='date').max()['Tgl/Waktu'] - df.groupby(by='date').min()['Tgl/Waktu'])\
.reset_index().rename(columns={'Tgl/Waktu': 'hours_worked'})
df = df.merge(hours_worked, on='date', how='left')
df['hours_worked'] = df.hours_worked.dt.seconds / 3600
```

Output:

```
    Nama    No.ID           Tgl/Wakt No.PIN Kode Verifikasi date    time     hours_worked
0   Alif    100061  2022-12-17 07:53:26 NaN Sidik Jari  2022-12-17  07:53:26    5.116389
1   Alif    100061  2022-12-17 13:00:25 NaN Sidik Jari  2022-12-17  13:00:25    5.116389
2   Alif    100061  2022-12-19 07:54:59 NaN Sidik Jari  2022-12-19  07:54:59    8.387500
3   Alif    100061  2022-12-19 16:18:14 NaN Sidik Jari  2022-12-19  16:18:14    8.387500
4   Alif    100061  2022-12-20 07:55:54 NaN Sidik Jari  2022-12-20  07:55:54    8.339444
5   Alif    100061  2022-12-20 16:16:16 NaN Sidik Jari  2022-12-20  16:16:16    8.339444
6   Alif    100061  2022-12-21 07:54:46 NaN Sidik Jari  2022-12-21  07:54:46    8.348611
7   Alif    100061  2022-12-21 16:15:41 NaN Sidik Jari  2022-12-21  16:15:41    8.348611
8   Alif    100061  2022-12-22 07:55:54 NaN Sidik Jari  2022-12-22  07:55:54    8.334722
9   Alif    100061  2022-12-22 16:15:59 NaN Sidik Jari  2022-12-22  16:15:59    8.334722
10  Alif    100061  2022-12-23 07:56:26 NaN Sidik Jari  2022-12-23  07:56:26    8.341667
11  Alif    100061  2022-12-23 16:16:56 NaN Sidik Jari  2022-12-23  16:16:56    8.341667
```

Comment: how do i remove the same one, so there is only one hours_worked output for 2 rows

Comment: .drop_duplicates(subset=["date"]), but it is another question, did I answer your previous ones?

Comment: when i run it i get different hours_worked output, https://colab.research.google.com/drive/154ku-sREv4gDKmTumBOpZelBO37bdMgl?usp=sharing
that's the link to my code, is it something I type isn't right?

for the 0 and 1 row I get 5.86666666666667 hours_worked

Comment: your colab says 5.116389